# mysql server: stored procedures - when do i create the stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I found tutorials on creating a stored procedures on the net, I just don't understand when exactly do I need to execute the creation of the stored procedure.

do the stored procedures creation should be executed each time i restart my MySQL server ?

do I need to execute the stored procedures creation sql each time I start my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedures are persisted to the database, ie they will be there even after a restart of the database server. You create them once and then you run them as often as you need. Of course you may want to change them sometimes using an alter statement.